# Symfony 4: Re-install VichUploaderBundle?

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, vichuploaderbundle

I have installed [VichUploaderBundle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4ZIp.png) with command

```
composer require vich/uploader-bundle
```

but I forgot enter yes like the above image (default is no). And I see any VichUploaderBundle package in my app. How can I relaunch it without reinstall it?

Comment: What would happen if you removed the package and simply required it afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

As vich/uploader-bundle is installed via [a recipe](https://github.com/symfony/recipes-contrib/tree/master/vich/uploader-bundle/1.5), you could relaunch this recipe.

Force reinstallation without removing then requiring it:

```
composer recipes:install vich/uploader-bundle --force -v
```

Here is some other useful command to use with recipes:

```
#List all recipes
composer recipes

#See detailed information about your bundle
composer recipes vich/uploader-bundle
```

Comment: Thanks your reply. But I didn't find neither vich_uploader.yaml in config\packages nor app\AppKernel.php for registering this bundle. How can I do, Mister?

Comment: Is flex installed ? Could you edit your question to add the composer.json content ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no other solution than remove it and then re-install it again using these commands

```
composer remove vich/uploader-bundle

cache:clear

composer require vich/uploader-bundle
```